# htaccess rewrite to a script when the requested file does not exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope you can help. I'm trying to write a `.htaccess` file to do the following.

1. redirect to `www.` address
2. remove `.php` from URL
3. If the file doesn't exist then use `filechecker.php?page=filename`

---

#1 I can do with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

#2 I can do with

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
```

---

#3 I thought

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ filechecker.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

would work, but for some reason it is ignoring the fact that the page does actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution for 2 will loop, but simple enough to fix, stick something along the following lines in your file for part 2 and 3:

```
#If the Browser request contains a .php, instruct the browser to remove it.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}      \.php      [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$       http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1         [R=301,NC,L]

#If a request is received for a non file-system object, that doesn't have a .php suffix, then store the full path, filename, and URI in a variables with that extention.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^\.php$  [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$      -  [E=testScript:%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php,E=testFile:$1.php,E=testURI:%{REQUEST_URI}.php]

#See if the file exists with a .php extention, if it does internally rewrite
RewriteCond %{ENV:testScript} -s  [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:testScript} -f
RewriteRule .*              %{ENV:testURI} [L]

#Else if a ENV:testDile is set, then pass the name to the php script
RewriteCond %{ENV:testFile} !^$
RewriteRule .*               /filechecker.php?page=%{ENV:testFile} [L]
```

FYI: The Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation is worth a read, if your unclear as to what the above rules do, or if you want something a little more abstract consider the following [post](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Web_Servers/Apache/A_4043).