# How to redirect old site url that ends with .html to the new site's home page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Ok, I have these old urls:

```
http://www.example.com/services.html
http://www.example.com/about.html
```

I want to redirect all incoming requests that have .html in it to just the homepage of the site http://www.example.com. Keep in mind "old" and "new" domainname are actually the same ie. `example.com`

I tried this but htaccess rules are not my strongest side:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You should check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370004/htaccess-rewritecond-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule by this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule \.html$ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```